# SQLITE Full text: How to find all rows containing words with specific size?

Tags: sqlite

I have a sqlite3 full text search table defined like this:

`CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE dataset USING fts3(content TEXT);`

### Sample content:

```
content
=======
1 I like potatoes
2 Do you want a bottle?
3 I have loose my computer games
```

### If my search is:

1. find all row contains words with **8 letters**. The result must be **(1, 3)** because we have **potatoes** and **computer**
2. find all row contains words with **5 letters**. The result must be **(3)** because we have **loose**
3. find all row contains words with **4 letters**. The result must be **(1, 2** and **3)** because we have **like**, **want** and **have**

Comment: Can you use fts5 instead?

Comment: I can use only fts3 or fts4. It's for sqlite android apk

Comment: Darn. It's trivial with fts5, but older versions don't give enough access to the indexes. Hmm. Does the Android version of sqlite provide any support for regular expressions, and if so, what flavor?

Comment: Here you can find all version by API [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary) I use API23

Comment: That says nothing about what extensions and user-defined functions android bundles into sqlite.

Comment: Nop :/ Can you send me the request for an FTS5 please ? I have found a link for an android FTS5 https://github.com/plangrid/SQLite-FTS5-Android  I can test that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FTS5](https://sqlite.org/fts5.html) solution. This makes use of the [fts5vocab virtual table](https://sqlite.org/fts5.html#the_fts5vocab_virtual_table_module) mechanism that gives a public interface to the internal index tables used by the search engine (FTS3/4 has a similar [fts4aux virtual table](https://sqlite.org/fts3.html#fts4aux) but it doesn't provide the same feature set and can't be used to determine the exact rows a term appears in).

```
sqlite> CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE dataset USING fts5(content);
sqlite> CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE dataset_vocab USING fts5vocab(dataset, instance);
sqlite> INSERT INTO dataset(rowid, content) VALUES (1, 'I like potatoes'), (2, 'Do you want a bottle?'), (3, 'I have loose my computer games');
sqlite> SELECT DISTINCT doc FROM dataset_vocab WHERE length(term) = 8 ORDER BY doc;
doc
----------
1
3
sqlite> SELECT DISTINCT doc FROM dataset_vocab WHERE length(term) = 5 ORDER BY doc;
doc
----------
3
sqlite> SELECT DISTINCT doc FROM dataset_vocab WHERE length(term) = 4 ORDER BY doc;
doc
----------
1
2
3
```

Without FTS5, you'd have to break each column into individual words yourself and return just those of the appropriate length. With this, the FTS5 tokenizer does the hard part for you.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I must use it on android now :)